# Visual studio references show some libraries not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maven

I have been working maven projects since 2 two years.First of all, I import maven projects to eclipse then
thanks to my pom.xml some dependencies is installed and I see these dependencies on my maven dependencies folder on eclipe project explorer.It connected to my .M2 folder.

Right now , I import a .Net framework project (which is written with C#)  in my visual studio program.The solution explorer (references section) show many dependencies(they gives error).Then I found these libraries then I created a folder which is called nugetPackages  and I connected my nuget packages manager to that folder(tools/options/nuget package manager/package sources).I reopen my project and libraries on references section does not give any error.My question is  where does that libraries names come from ? There are any file like that pom.xml.

I hope I can explain my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the libraries (DLLs) that you want to reference in your project NuGet packages or just some framework libraries? If they are Nuget packages they should be described in packages.config file http://prntscr.com/1140xn0 for the classic .NET application (.net framework 4.5 for example) In a .Net Core applications the Nuget packages that are required are defined in the file .csproj file http://prntscr.com/11412iq. In both cases, you can download all required NuGet packages by right clicking on the .sln file and selecting Restore Nuget Packages http://prntscr.com/1140zsk This will automatically create the nugget folder and download all required Nuget packages. If you have manually added dlls you need to navigate to them and select them by right-clicking References - Add reference http://prntscr.com/114142x

Comment: My project contains package.config file and it has 4 package definition.Also project contains package folder( contains 4 nuget pakages) but my references section contains also other libraries.As far as I  understand , package folder is unnecessary because restore nuget package command download all packages which is defined in package.config

Comment: Yes and the other dlls that do not come from NuGet most likely are part of the Framework and you have to link them manually.